# How to use npm correctly in WSL 2?

Tags: typescript, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, npx

I have installed npm as usual in the Debian App on Windows with WSL 2:

```
sudo apt install npm
```

Then I have created my test project where I have installed typescript:

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm install typescript --save-dev
```

Then I have tested the binary paths with `which`:

```
/usr/bin/npm
/usr/bin/node
```

Then I wanted to try [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_getstarted.php) by installing `typescript` and running the command `npx tsc`, which is an alias for `npm exec tsc`. All the help for commands of tsc are printed well, but, at the end part of the ouput I gets this errors. I don't really know if they are related to WSL, but I am afraid so:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/MyName/ts_test
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c tsc

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/db/.npm/_logs/2022-05-10T13_04_55_773Z-debug.log
```

The debug log does not drop any more information about the error.

Any advice? Should I use npm in a Windows terminal and forget about WSL?

Comment: You forgot to run `npm install typescript --save-dev`

Comment: Ah no, @ikhvjs, I didn't forget about it, I've followed the steps in the tutorial. I will add it to the question to take into account. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was some problem with node version. I had the version that Debian installed, v12. I have updated the node version and the error disappeared. So the error was not related to WSL.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

hash -r     # reset bash to show version
node -v     # show node version
```

In spite of that, `tsconfig.json` didn't show up. I have read that the command to create it, at the first time, should be:

```
npx tsc --init
```